# Телефонный справочник, Добавить и Удалить данные в массив Java

Tags: java, массивы, классы

Задача такая:

> Написать телефонный справочник, в котором есть три функции: найти, добавить, удалить.

Мне нужно создать массив в котором будут данные справочника, и работать с ним.

Я не могу понять как мне добавить данные человека из `saveContact` в массив? И удалить из массива?

```java
import java.util.List;                                                                                                                                 
import java.util.Scanner;
                                                                                                                              
public class CompInfoHighway extends Main {                                                                                                             
    public CompInfoHighway(String kategory, String surname, String name1, String patronymic, String location, String email, String number) {           
        super(kategory, surname, name1, patronymic, location, email, number);                                                                          
    }                                                                                                                                                  
 
    public static void fail(){                                                                                                                         
        CompInfoHighway[] list = new CompInfoHighway[25];                                                                                              
        list[0] = new CompInfoHighway("Универ", "Иван","Иванов","Иванович","Сатпаева 22 А","ivan@gmail.com", "87751111111");           
        list[1] = new CompInfoHighway("Работа", "Сергеев","Сергей","Аскарович","Назарбаева 115","sergey@gmail.com","87059963255");         
        list[2] = new CompInfoHighway("Танцы","Димов","Дима","Димович","Казыбек би 22/1","Dima@gmail.com","87756591232");            
        list[3] = new CompInfoHighway("Медицина", "Евгеньев", "Евгений", "Евгенивич", "Муратбаева 114/120","zhenya@gmail.com","87778578367");     
        list[4] = new CompInfoHighway("Медицина","Владимиров","Владимир","Владимерович","Темирязева 56","Vladimer@mail.ru","87776549874");                 
        list[5] = new CompInfoHighway("Танцы","Петров","Петр","Петрович","Абая 110","Petr3@gmail.com","87054896523");                                                                                                                                                                                             
    }                                                                                                                                                  
 
    public static void main(String[] args) { displayMenu();}                                                                                           
 
    public static void saveContact(String kategory, String surname, String name, String patronymic, String location, String email, String number){     
        System.out.println("Контакт сохранен:"+ kategory+" "+surname+" "+name+" "+patronymic+" "+location+" "+email+" "+number);                       
    }                                                                                                                                                  
    public static void findNumber(String Name){                                                                                                        
        System.out.println("");                                                                                                                        
    }                                                                                                                                                  
    public static void displayMenu(){                                                                                                                  
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);                                                                                                           
        System.out.println("Что вы хотите сделать?");                                                                                                  
        System.out.println("1. Сохранить контакт");                                                                               
        System.out.println("2. Найти контакт");    
        System.out.println("3. Удалить контакт");
                                                                                 
 
        int choice = in.nextInt(); //выберете что хотите сделать                                                                                       
        in.nextLine();                                                                                                                                 
        switch(choice){                                                                                                                                
            case 1:                                                                                                                                    
                System.out.println("Введите категорию человека которого хотите добавить:");                                                            
                System.out.println("Пример: Семья,Универ,Работа,Медицина,Танцы. Можете добавить свою категорию");                                      
                String kategory = in.nextLine();                                                                                                       
                System.out.print("Введите фамилию человека которого хотите добавить:");                                                                
                String surname = in.nextLine();                                                                                                        
                System.out.println("Введите имя человека которого хотите добавить:");                                                                  
                String name = in.nextLine();                                                                                                           
                System.out.println("Введите отчество человека которого хотите добавить:");                                                             
                String patronymic = in.nextLine();                                                                                                     
                System.out.println("Введите адрес человека которого хотите добавить:");                                                                
                String location = in.nextLine();                                                                                                       
                System.out.println("Введите почту человека которого хотите добавить:");                                                                
                String email = in.nextLine();                                                                                                          
                System.out.println("Введите номер человека которого хотите добавить:");                                                                
                String number = in.nextLine();                                                                                                         
                saveContact(kategory, surname, name, patronymic, location, email, number);                                                             
 
                break;                                                                                                                                 
            case 2:                                                                                                                                    
                System.out.println("Как зовут человека, номер которого вы хотите найти?");                                                             
                name = in.nextLine();                                                                                                                  
                        System.out.println();                                                                                                          
                break;     
            case 3:
                        System.out.println("Как зовут человека которого вы хотите удалить?");                                                                                        
            default:                                                                                                                                   
                break;                                                                                                                                 
        }                                                                                                                                              
    }                                                                                                                                                  
}
```

```java
public class Main {
    private String kategory;
    private String surname;
    private String name1;
    private String patronymic;
    private String location;
    private String email;
    private String number;
 
    public Main(String kategory, String surname, String name1, String patronymic,
                String location, String email, String number) {
        this.kategory = kategory;
        this.surname = surname;
        this.name1 = name1;
        this.patronymic = patronymic;
        this.location = location;
        this.email = email;
        this.number = number;
    }
    public String getKategory(){return kategory;}
    public void setKategory(String kategory){this.kategory = kategory;}
 
    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }
    public void setSurname(String surname) {
        this.surname = surname;
    }
 
    public String getName() {
        return name1;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name1 = name;
    }
 
    public String getPatronymic() {
        return patronymic;
    }
    public void setPatronymic(String patronymic) {
        this.patronymic = patronymic;
    }
 
    public String getLocation() {
        return location;
    }
    public void setLocation(String location) {
        this.location = location;
    }
 
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
 
    public String getNumber() {
        return number;
    }
    public void setNumber(String number) { this.number = number;
    }
 
    // чтобы информация отображалась в PhoneNumber
    public void showFullName() {
        System.out.println(surname + " " +  name1 + " " + patronymic);
    }
}
```

Comment: Так тебе нужен не массив, а список) Юзай ArrayList()

Comment: Для телефонного справочника я бы посоветовал HashMap

Comment: Нужно создать `private static int count = 0;` и юзать ее для счетчика массива. Вместо каждого вызова `list[5] = new CompInfoHighway("Танцы",...` юзать `list[count++] = new CompInfoHighway("Танцы",...`. Ну и конечно помнить, что массив когда-нибудь закончится, поэтому см. советы выше. К тому же, если оставите массив, то поимеете гемор с удалением - надо будет или сдвигать элементы массива, или заполнять `null`-ами и вести счетчик, короче гемор...

Answer (score 0):

В комментариях написал, что добавил. Всё же лучше использовать *динамические массивы*, к примеру **ArrayList**. Почитай про массивы и область видимости, удачи.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CompInfoHighway extends Main {
    public CompInfoHighway(String kategory, String surname, String name1, String patronymic, String location, String email, String number) {
        super(kategory, surname, name1, patronymic, location, email, number);
    }

    static CompInfoHighway[] list = new CompInfoHighway[25]; //выносим массив за границы метода fail, чтобы увеличить его область видимости, чтобы он был доступен в методе saveContact
    static int idContact = 6; //индекс следующего элемента массива, он равен 6 так как добавлено в fail медоте 6 элементов с (0 по 5)

    public static void fail() {
        //убрали отсюда массив list
        list[0] = new CompInfoHighway("Универ", "Иван", "Иванов", "Иванович", "Сатпаева 22 А", "ivan@gmail.com", "87751111111");
        list[1] = new CompInfoHighway("Работа", "Сергеев", "Сергей", "Аскарович", "Назарбаева 115", "sergey@gmail.com", "87059963255");
        list[2] = new CompInfoHighway("Танцы", "Димов", "Дима", "Димович", "Казыбек би 22/1", "Dima@gmail.com", "87756591232");
        list[3] = new CompInfoHighway("Медицина", "Евгеньев", "Евгений", "Евгенивич", "Муратбаева 114/120", "zhenya@gmail.com", "87778578367");
        list[4] = new CompInfoHighway("Медицина", "Владимиров", "Владимир", "Владимерович", "Темирязева 56", "Vladimer@mail.ru", "87776549874");
        list[5] = new CompInfoHighway("Танцы", "Петров", "Петр", "Петрович", "Абая 110", "Petr3@gmail.com", "87054896523");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        displayMenu();
    }

    public static void saveContact(String kategory, String surname, String name, String patronymic, String location, String email, String number) {
        System.out.println("Контакт сохранен:" + kategory + " " + surname + " " + name + " " + patronymic + " " + location + " " + email + " " + number);
        //добавляем ССЫЛКУ на объект в массив
        list[idContact] = new CompInfoHighway(kategory, surname, name, patronymic, location, email, number);
        idContact++;
    }

    public static void findNumber(String Name) {
        System.out.println("");
    }

    public static void displayMenu() {
        fail(); //вызвываем метод fail чтобы заполнить list
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Что вы хотите сделать?");
        System.out.println("1. Сохранить контакт");
        System.out.println("2. Найти контакт");
        System.out.println("3. Удалить контакт");


        int choice = in.nextInt(); //выберете что хотите сделать                                                                                       
        in.nextLine();
        switch (choice) {
            case 1:
                System.out.println("Введите категорию человека которого хотите добавить:");
                System.out.println("Пример: Семья,Универ,Работа,Медицина,Танцы. Можете добавить свою категорию");
                String kategory = in.nextLine();
                System.out.print("Введите фамилию человека которого хотите добавить:");
                String surname = in.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Введите имя человека которого хотите добавить:");
                String name = in.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Введите отчество человека которого хотите добавить:");
                String patronymic = in.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Введите адрес человека которого хотите добавить:");
                String location = in.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Введите почту человека которого хотите добавить:");
                String email = in.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Введите номер человека которого хотите добавить:");
                String number = in.nextLine();
                saveContact(kategory, surname, name, patronymic, location, email, number);

                break;
            case 2:
                System.out.println("Как зовут человека, номер которого вы хотите найти?");
                name = in.nextLine();
                System.out.println();
                break;
            case 3:
                System.out.println("Как зовут человека которого вы хотите удалить?");
            default:
                break;
        }
     //вывод всех контактов
     for (int i = 0; i < idContact; i++)
            list[i].showFullName();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

метод вызывается у экземпляра класса в виде `object.saveContact()`
учитывая что мы в данный момент находимся внутри метода класса,
т.е. только что сделали вызов `object.displayMenu()` для ссылки на `object.` внутри метода класса используется `this.`

`this.saveContact( ... )`

Comment: Тут все методы статические...